# How to get foreign key value for independent association without hitting database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using independent associations (with lazy loading) to access related entities in my code first model e.g.

```
public class Aaa {
  public int AaaId {get;set;}
  public string SomeValue {get;set;}
}

public class Bbb {
  public int BbbId {get;set;}
  public string SomeValue {get;set;}
  public virtual Aaa MyIndependentAssociation {get;set;}
}
```

but I am wondering how to access the foreign key value of `MyIndependentAssociation` without actually loading the record.

I am assuming the `Aaa_AaaId` value is actually loaded when I retrieve a `Bbb` entity from the database (according the debug visualizer on the entity table anyway).

How do I get access to the value (other than adding a Foreign Key association into my model)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible. With your example model you can find the foreign key values the following way:

```
Bbb bbb = myDbContext.Bbbs.First();

var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext;

var relMgr = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(bbb);
var relEnds = relMgr.GetAllRelatedEnds();
var relEnd = relEnds.Single(); // because yor model has exactly one relationship
var entityRef = relEnd as EntityReference<Aaa>;    
var entityKey = entityRef.EntityKey;

int foreignKeyValue = (int)entityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;

// to confirm that no database query happened
Console.WriteLine(entityRef.IsLoaded); // outputs false
```

In the more general case where you have multiple relationships in the `Bbb` class and maybe even more than one navigation property refering to `Aaa` you need to find the correct element in the `relEnds` enumeration. You could also have composite foreign keys. It would look like this then:

```
Bbb bbb = myDbContext.Bbbs.First();

var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext;

var relMgr = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(bbb);
var entityRef = relMgr.GetRelatedReference<Aaa>(
    "MyEntityNamespace.Bbb_MyIndependentAssociation",
    "Bbb_MyIndependentAssociation_Target");
var entityKey = entityRef.EntityKey;

object[] compositeForeignKeyValues =
    entityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();

// to confirm that no database query happened
Console.WriteLine(entityRef.IsLoaded); // outputs false
```

Note, that `IsLoaded` can be `true` if you inspect the `entityRef` object in the debugger which can cause the related object to be loaded (even though lazy loading is disabled).

Comment: Great, detailed answer. Thanks

Comment: P.S. In the end I decided to use both foreign keys AND independent associations in my models because it avoids this complex code. The downside is something of a technicality: your model exposes an "implementation detail" which the original EF designers wanted you to avoid in your "conceptual model". It's debatable whether code-first models are conceptual or storage models.

Comment: +1: your answer solved my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451766/ef-5-get-foreign-key-value-for-navigation-property