# EF 5 - Get foreign key value for navigation property

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to get the foreign key value for a navigation property, without having to define the foreign key property (before the navigation property is loaded).

**Why?**

We cache (for instance) all "status"-objects application wide (yes we couldn't use enums for this). When we load an object with a navigation property to this status-class the repository will set the property to the cached item.

I could go with a foreign key property, but since EF knows the key, I would like to get it from EF (maybe through the RelationshipManager or the DBEntityReference for the navigation property) but I can't seem to find it.

*Note*: I am using EF5, code first in .Net 4.5

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but is just having a `StatusId` property in your entities not enough?

Comment: Could be the shortcut fallback solution. However when using a foreign key property Id, you'll need to keep the property and the navigation property in sync or find a way to hide it from the api (by using an inner class with accessor properties). It all looks kinda messy, for IMHO something quite simple.

Comment: With EF it's quite common to expose primitive FK fields (which is called _foreign key associations_). EF keeps them in sync with FK references when detecting changes.

Comment: @GertArnold only when they are marked as virtual. EF then injects a dynamic proxy that takes care of this. The dynamic proxy will not use the cached objects, but instead load from the database. If you don't use virtual it's your own responsibility to keep them in sync

Comment: With proxies it happens real time, otherwise in `DbContext.DetectChanges()` (implicit in `SaveChanges`).

Comment: @GertArnold: didn't know that. Thanks. Kind of makes me wondering how EF can do that with detached objects. Probably by doing additional queries to the Db. (will probably add concurrency issues?) But I am sidetracking here...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer (on stackoverflow) from [Slauma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334534/how-to-get-foreign-key-value-for-independent-association-without-hitting-databas?rq=1) (not sure if I should mark this as duplicate?). I had to change the code a litle to handle an entity with multiple relations. A lot of stuff is still ugly but it works :)

```
RelationshipManager relMgr = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(document);
IEnumerable<IRelatedEnd> relEnds = relMgr.GetAllRelatedEnds();
IRelatedEnd relEnd = relEnds.Where(r => r.RelationshipName.EndsWith("Document_Status")).Single();
EntityReference<Status> entityRef = relEnd as EntityReference<Status>;
var entityKey = entityRef.EntityKey;

short statusId =(short)entityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

The only downside is that (As far as I can tell. Hope someone finds a better way?) this information is lost as soon as you detach the entity or when you load it with AsNoTracking().