# How to get RelationshipName for navigation property?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

*Short question:* 
What is a robust way for finding RelationshipName of independent association using navigation property?

*Long question:*

For example, let's say I have following entities.

```
public class EntityA
{
    public EntityA Parent { get; set; }
    public EntityA Child { get; set; }

    public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}
```

All associations are one-to-one independent associations so there are no explicit foreign keys for them. However, EntityFramework is storing the foreign keys internally and I should be able to access them by using RelationshipManager ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334534/how-to-get-foreign-key-value-for-independent-association-without-hitting-databas)).

```
EntityA myEntity = ...;

var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
RelationshipManager relMgr = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(myEntity);
IEnumerable<IRelatedEnd> relEnds = relMgr.GetAllRelatedEnds();

var reference = (EntityReference)relEnds.Where(x => x.RelationshipName == "Mynamespace.EntityA_EntityB").FirstOrDefault();
var foreignKey = (Int64)reference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

Basically this method requires me to get all relationships that an entity has and filter them by RelationshipName. Now I'm wondering what is the proper way to get the RelationshipName based on actual navigation property on the entity, i.e. I would like to have a method that I could use like:

```
// How do I write "GetRelationshipName" method?
string relationshipName = GetRelationshipName<EntityA>(a => a.EntityB);
var reference = relEnds.Where(x => x.RelationshipName == relationshipName).FirstOrDefault();
```

One of the problems seems to be that RelationshipName for both *EntityA.EntityB* and *EntityB.EntityA* are *same*. I was expecting other name to be "Mynamespace.EntityA_EntityB" and other to be "Mynamesapce.EntityB_EntityA" but that is not the case. Also, if entity is referencing itself it becomes even more difficult, e.g. in this case the name for both relationships *EntityA.Parent* and *EntityA.Child* would be either "Mynamespace.EntityA_Parent" or "Mynamespace.EntityA_Child".

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Ever figured this out?